# Is there a nonstop flight from the west coast of North America to anywhere in India?

Tags: air-travel, usa, india

A friend in San Francisco is trying to figure it out, given that there are (apparently) nonstop flights to Dubai, it should be physically possible, but wondering if such flights exist?

Comment: Physically Possible and Makes Economic Sense are often two different things when it comes to flights... Don't forget that quite a few "very long" routes have been announced then cancelled of late, eg [Singapore-Newark](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052970203937004578076560046135292) lost money

Comment: It's physically possible to fly to the moon, but I don't know of any direct flights there, either :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, their point was it's physically possible AND economically possible to fly to Dubai, so the assumption was there may be one to India as well, especially given the high population and migration.  However, as yet, there doesn't appear to be such a route.  There was also going to be a Auckland to Chicago route at one point, but the demand wasn't high enough.

Comment: It's more than a thousand km from Dubai to India.

Comment: New Delhi is closer to LA than Dubai is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The earlier accepted answer by JonathanReez was written in 2014. From December 2015, [Air India operates a San Francisco - Delhi flight](https://airwaysmag.com/airlines/air-india-inaugurates-nonstop-service-between-san-francisco-and-delhi/).

Answer (score 8):

**As of 2014**, Singapore Airlines Cargo provides a cargo flight [from Los Angeles to Mumbai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chhatrapati_Shivaji_International_Airport#Cargo_airlines). Otherwise no such flights exist from LAX, SFO or YVR (the only likely candidates).

**As of 2015**, a new flight has opened up between San Francisco and Delhi, as correctly mentioned above.

Comment: I might think of SEA as another candidate, but it doesn't have any flights to India either.